# Is saving a private key encrypted with the users password safer than storing a hash in a database?

Tags: cryptography, passwords, password-hash, password-storage

Is storing a private key generated by the client that is encrypted by the users password safer than storing a hash of a password? (The encryption part is done client side and it will be sent to the server the users password won't be sent to the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you're talking about.

If i'm the client:

- i generate a pure random *"key"*:
  `58 3b ae a9 de 37 88 e6 ed a2 9f 45 db 8b 9f 56 ef e1 aa 25 ac 52 f6 3d 02 dd 1b 86 1f c5 39 44`
- i encrypt it with a password:
  `3e 35 33 46 fe a2 04 09 58 ff 1a 29 41 97 cb 6d 44 32 5f 4a 74 01 90 1d f3 32 eb 2c 6e 49 e1 19`

What you've done is have the client create a strong password with extra steps. I can convert those bytes to a string:

> `4uG,crh9N%=T99g6'oc36o&+AF9.IDo.oV_DFre)`

This is now the user's *"password"*. When they login to your site, you need to validate that password. That means that you **must** securely store that password in your system - *and taking the SHA-256 hash of that password is not secure*.

### That's all if the client encrypts it

What if instead the user generates a *"private key"*:

> `58 3b ae a9 de 37 88 e6 ed a2 9f 45 db 8b 9f 56 ef e1 aa 25 ac 52 f6 3d 02 dd 1b 86 1f c5 39 44`

And they send **that** to the server, and **you** will encrypt it with the user's password: ***how did you know the user's password!?***

You can't do that, because you can't know their password.

Comment: I'm doing the encryption part on the client side and only the encrypted key will be sent to the server